# Unable to override the pre-authenticate and authenticate methods in adapters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

Unlike save_user and send_email in DefaultAccountAdapter, I am unable to override the pre_authenticate and authenticate methods. Please can someone explain why or how I can achieve these?

```
class DefaultAccountAdapterCustom(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def pre_authenticate(self,  request, **credentials):
        # Do something before authenticating
    
    def authenticate(self,  request, **credentials):
          # Do something after authenticating
```

Comment: These methods don't exist on that class. Where did you find them?

Comment: Here https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/adapter.py